# access new property in template

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to have an access to the host element custom property set from within a directive.

I have this code inside my directive:

```
@Directive({  selector: '[myDirective]'})
export class MyDirective {
...
  @HostListener('input')
  onInput() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.myProp = true;
  }
}
```

and this inside my template

```
<input MyDirective #myInput="ngModel" />
<p #myP>{{myInput.myProp}}</p>
<button [disabled]=myInput.myProp>Click</button>
```

I can see that the property is set in the typescript code (in the debugger and/or via logging) but it doesn't seem to affect the result code (`myP` is empty and the button is never disabled). Is it impossible or am I doing it the wrong way?

If above is impossible is there any other way to access my directive's host element custom property/attribute or (maybe even better) my directive instance itself via host element in the template? Something like that `[disabled]=myInput.myDirective.myProp`.

Comment: It shouldn't even be compiled with such assignment `#myInput="ngModel"`

Comment: Oh my... You are right. As far as I understand this way the `FormControl` instance is accessed, not an `input` element. Thank you!